# kotlin.KotlinNull on Fragment Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I always get this error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{batstate.companionemergencybutton/batstate.commutersalertbutton.SetupActivity}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException.

When starting my activity. The part of getAdapter on the setupActivity always crashes. I have checked my XML and i have already added the fragment component that includes the ProfileFragment. I think that i have not initialized my Profile fragment on the setup activity. But how can i setup that ?

**SetupActivity**

```
     private var mProfile: ProfileFragment? = null

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup)

        mProfile = ProfileFragment()

        mStatusListener = OnStatusChangeListener { status ->
            if (status === OnStatusChangeListener.Status.NO_ERROR)
                next_button!!.setEnabled(true)
            else
                next_button!!.setEnabled(false)
        }

     mProfile!!.getAdapter()!!.setOnStatusChangeListener(mStatusListener)
                    if (mProfile!!.getAdapter()!!.hasErrors())
```

**ProfileFragment**

```
class ProfileAdapter(private val mContext: Context) : BaseAdapter(), AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private val mInflater: LayoutInflater = mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    private val mData: ArrayList<HashMap<String, Any>> = ArrayList()

    // Event Listeners
    private var mOnStatusChangeListener: OnStatusChangeListener? = null

    override fun getItem(i: Int): HashMap<String, Any> {
        return mData[i]
    }

    override fun getItemId(i: Int): Long {
        return i.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return mData.size
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        var convertView = convertView
        val data = mData[position]
        val holder: ViewHolder
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, parent, false)
            holder = ViewHolder()
            holder.text1 = convertView!!.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.text1) as TextView
            holder.text2 = convertView.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.text2) as TextView
            convertView.tag = holder
        } else
            holder = convertView.tag as ViewHolder

        holder.text1!!.text = data["title"].toString()
        var value = data["value"].toString()
        if (value.isEmpty())
            value = "Tap to select"

        holder.text2!!.text = value

        return convertView
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        internal var text1: TextView? = null
        internal var text2: TextView? = null
    }

    fun hasErrors(): Boolean {
        for (data in mData) {
            if (data["value"].toString().isEmpty())
                return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: batstate.companionemergencybutton, PID: 20824
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{batstate.companionemergencybutton/batstate.commutersalertbutton.SetupActivity}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                    Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
                                                                                       at batstate.commutersalertbutton.SetupActivity.updateContent(SetupActivity.kt:102)
                                                                                       at batstate.commutersalertbutton.SetupActivity.onControlClicked(SetupActivity.kt:71)
                                                                                       at batstate.commutersalertbutton.SetupActivity.onCreate(SetupActivity.kt:36)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
```

BTW the

> (SetupActivity.kt:102)

error is `mProfile!!.getAdapter()!!.setOnStatusChangeListener(mStatusListener)`

Comment: show logcat please

Comment: post your crash report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fragment is null so  Before call fragment method commit it first. then use fragment methods

```
private var mProfile: ProfileFragment? = null
```

Inside onCreate

```
    if(savedInstanceState == null)
    {
    mProfile = new ProfileFragment();
    mProfile.setTag(R.id.myfragmentId);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, mProfile).commit();
    }
   else
   {
    if(mProfile == null)
    {
        mProfile = (ProfileFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(R.id.myfragmentId);
    }
    }
```

then

```
  mProfile!!.getAdapter()!!.setOnStatusChangeListener(mStatusListener)
                if (mProfile!!.getAdapter()!!.hasErrors())
```